# database name preceded with null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard

We are trying to back up a sqlite database to the SD CARD the database was created and lives in the emulator INTERNAL storage. The issue is when finding the path to the INTERNAL storage the return name for the DB is as it was named "PassWord" 
My question is why is the database name preceded with the words null in the Device File Explore? Android Studio 3.0 Build tools 26.0.2 YES Manifest permissions added example "nullPassWord" Code to backup to the SD CARD below.
If there is a better way to backup from Internal to External suggestions are welcomed. We do not want to use adb pull.

```
    public void onCOPY(View view){

    File sd = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];// THIS IS OK
    System.out.println("################ SD "+sd);
    //File dir = getDatabasePath("PassWord");
    //String currentDBPath = dir.getPath();
    // dir.getPath(); RETURNS This /data/user/0/package name/databases/PassWord
    String currentDBPath = "/data/user/0/package name/databases/nullPassWord/";
    System.out.println("################ Current DB Path "+currentDBPath);

    FileChannel source;
    FileChannel destination;

    String backupDBPath = "NewPassWord";

    File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in your DBHelper Class you have some variable in front of your code where you define your database name. Like THE_PATH + "PassWord" I will post code to find the correct path to the database in INTERNAL storage

```
 File dir  = getDatabasePath("PassWord").getAbsoluteFile();
    String currentDBPath = dir.getPath();
```

So remove the words THE_PATH and set the path in other code ?